# Removing NAs in a column

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have created a table and grouped it to show the responses to a question.
The responses were Yes or No, however one response was not recored so pulls through as NA. I have tried to remove it from my data set byt using filter() and na.omit but i cant seem to get either to work.

```
data%>%
  group_by(brands_doing_enough)%>%
  summarise(Number=n())%>%
  mutate("Percentage(%)"=Number/112*100)
```

any reccomendations on what to try next?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible sample/example of your data?

Comment: And what output you get when you use 'na.omit()'?

Comment: I cant provide my data as it is from a survey, it is a large data set and the column includes yes and no with one NA

Comment: it just doesnt return any tables

Comment: You *can* provide data - it doesn't have to be your real data, just made up some. It's simple, for instance, `df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)` - just make sure it's in the same structure as yours and you will get much better, faster help. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure I follow, as your example code has seemingly nothing to do with your stated problem. Do you mean that your dataset has a column (Question X) which only has NAs in it and you'd like to remove that column?

If so, no need to mess around with the NAs, just remove the column:

```
data %>% select(-columnname)
```